# SAS Spool Errors with String Masking

Tags: sas

This is driving me mad now. I am trying to mask all the special characters in a particular line of a SAS plan file being used during a grid installation that I have pulled into a dataset:

```
if test_item = %str(<Machine Id=%'$machine:)&mach_num.%str(' Name=')&mach_name.%str(%'>) then end2 = end1;
```

The log is printed below. I see to be getting spool errors (possibly because something has not been masked correctly), however the `MPRINT` to the log suggests that the macro variable compilation has executed correctly.

```
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable FUNC_VAR resolves to test
MPRINT(PLAN_FINDER):   data test_plan4;
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable FUNC_VAR resolves to test
MPRINT(PLAN_FINDER):   set test_plan3;
MPRINT(PLAN_FINDER):   by ret_sort;
MPRINT(PLAN_FINDER):   retain end2;
388: LINE and COLUMN cannot be determined.
NOTE: NOSPOOL is on. Rerunning with OPTION SPOOL might allow recovery of the LINE and COLUMN where the error has occurred.
ERROR 388-185: Expecting an arithmetic operator.
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable MACH_NUM resolves to 2
SYMBOLGEN:  Macro variable MACH_NAME resolves to Metadata Server
76: LINE and COLUMN cannot be determined.
NOTE: NOSPOOL is on. Rerunning with OPTION SPOOL might allow recovery of the LINE and COLUMN where the error has occurred.
ERROR 76-322: Syntax error, statement will be ignored.

           ________
           49
MPRINT(PLAN_FINDER):   if test_item = <Machine Id='$machine:2' Name='Metadata Server'> then end2 = end1;
MPRINT(PLAN_FINDER):   else if end1 = 1 then end2 = end1 + end2;
MPRINT(PLAN_FINDER):   run;
```

Can anyone advise what I have done incorrectly?

The code:

```
%macro test(func_var, mach_num, mach_name);

data &func_var._plan4;
set &func_var._plan3;
by ret_sort;
retain end2;
if test_item = %str(<Machine Id=%'$machine:)&mach_num.%str(' Name=')&mach_name.%str(%'>) then end2 = end1;
else if end1 = 1 then end2 = end1 + end2;
run;

%mend;

%test(test, 2, Metadata Server);
```

Expected resolution of string in `test_item`:

```
<Machine Id='$machine:2' Name='Metadata Server'>
```

Thanks

Comment: Why are you using macro logic in a data step. You need to post more of the code to allow us to understand your log. Also, what do you expect that code to resolve to?

Comment: the datastep is in a macro loop...I will edit the question to show the loop now...

Comment: Show a realized, complete string that you are testing for, as well as the structural construct of the string value (the different embedded fields, their values and sources of their values (data set variable and/or macro variable)

Comment: I have edited now to include required components of question.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know why you think you need the masking. It's possible it's more complex than I think but it also seems like a lot of unnecessary work to me.

This works as expected for me, let me know how if it works for what you're trying to do.

```
test_item = "<Machine Id='$machine:&mach_num.' Name='&mach_name'>"
```

Test in a data step:

```
%let mach_name=Metadata Server;
%let mach_num=2;

data test;
test_item = "<Machine Id='$machine:&mach_num.' Name='&mach_name'>" ;
run;

proc print data=test;
run;
```

Results:

> `test_item = <Machine Id='$machine:2' Name='Metadata Server'>`

Comment: The issue I have with this is the following being printed to the log: MPRINT(PLAN_FINDER):   if test_item = "<Machine Id='$machine:2' Name='Metadata Server'>" then end2 = end1;

Comment: does that mean it thinks the quotes are part of the macro variable?

Comment: because if I pass instead "<Machine Id='$machine:2' Name='Metadata Server'>" I get the result I want...with the macro variables though the retain statement does not recognize the row in question as resolving to the desired string from the macro inputs...im sure I have had this issue before when searching for quoted macro variables within a dataset in a macro loop...

Comment: There’s no RETAIN shown in your code and that sounds like a separate issue.

Comment: Sorry, I see the RETAIN, but I don't see what the issue is what you've posted as from the log. Can your clarify as to what the issue is? You should see quotations marks in the log.